# Is there any good grunt ftp plugin?

Tags: deployment, ftp, gruntjs

I've tried `grunt-ftpush` and `grunt-ftp-deploy` but both doesn't work properly. I experience annoyning bugs with them. FTP task seems very important and it's weird that I can't google working one.

**UPDATED**

Here is settings for grunt-ftp

```
ftp: { 
  options: { 
    host: 'myhostname',
    user: 'myusername',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  },
  upload: { 
    files: { 
      'codebase/myprojectfolder': 'build/*' 
    }
  }
}
```

I expect that my local folder `build` will be copied to the server but I got an error

```
Fatal error: Unable to read "build/scripts" file (Error code: EISDIR).
```

Documentation is very poor, so I have no idea how to upload folders which has folders in it.

Comment: I know that this is old, but I recently found it.
grunt-ftp only handles files, grunt-ftp-deploy only handles directories. Couldn't find something that handles both

Answer (score 4):

I tried many FTP plugins and, to my mind, only ftp_push was good enough for me. All other plugins lie on minimap which seemed buggy (when selecting which files to upload or not). Moreover, the idea to use a separate file to handle auth keys has no viable using : if we want to store FTP data in an external JSON file and put it inside our Gruntfile.js, it is not possible at all... The developer should choose by himself what to do with authentification and not rely on an external auth system.

Anyway, the project is alive and Robert-W has fix many issues really quickly : it's a major advantage too when we're developing. Projects that are quite dead are really painful.

https://github.com/Robert-W/grunt-ftp-push

Comment: "if we want to store FTP data in an external JSON file and put it inside our Gruntfile.js"
That  isn't true this is how my gruntfile looks like : http://pastebin.com/fuT6HiEZ

Comment: I was talking about some specific libraries that force the user to store its data in a 'ftp_auth.ext' file. The file name depends on the library, and often it requires that the file is stored beside the grunt file. Which I really don't like because a grunt/gulp project has already many files at the root.

Comment: I rather have 2 files than commit my ftp username/psw in github :p

Comment: Exactly, and we can put all conf files in the same place and don't have to search for the lines to change for each project ^^

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for a actual working way to pushing single files for quite a while, but I come down to using a shell script that makes the ftp call and run the script with `grunt-exec` ([npm link](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-exec)). This seemed way simpler than getting any of the ftp plugins to work. This would work for any *nix system.

script.sh

```
ftp -niv ftp.host.com << EOF
user foo_user password
cd /path/to/destination
put thefilepush.txt
EOF
```

Gruntfile.js

```
exec: {
  ftpupload: {
    command: './script.sh'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes grunt-ftp and [grunt-sftp-deploy](https://github.com/thrashr888/grunt-sftp-deploy) worked well for me.

Comment: when I launched `grunt-sftp-deploy` it got freeze and after a couple of minutes I saw memory leak in Activity Monitor. 1.2G was consumed by grunt, so I remove this plugin immediately.

Comment: Are you running the newest version of Node?

Comment: No, I have v0.10.23 and happy with it

Comment: OK. Then that should not be the problem I guess. Sorry I have no idea why it doesn't work for you. It worked fine for me. Do you have SSH access to the server? Because you could use https://github.com/jedrichards/grunt-rsync or https://github.com/andrewrjones/grunt-ssh.

Comment: What about ftps options like Explicit SSL/TLS and passive mode?  I can't find a single grunt ftps component that allows setting both these.

Answer (score 0):

Try [grunt-ftp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-ftp)

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ftp: {                       // Task
    options: {                 // Options
     host: 'website.com',
      user: 'johndoe',
      pass: '1234'
    },
    upload: {                  // Target
      files: {                 // Dictionary of files
        'public_html': 'src/*' // remote destination : source
      }
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ftp');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['ftp']);
```

Comment: Not good as well. It has problem reading folders. No surprise here, this plugin has only one download from npm.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to configure them? Expand your question a bit with more info.

Answer (score 0):

After following old or misinformation I was finally to get grunt-ftps-deploy to work for uploading individual files to a remote server inside a docker.  Here is the grunt task:

```
ftps_deploy: {
        deploy: {
              options: {
                auth:{
                  host:'xx.xx.xx.xx',
                  authKey: 'key1',
                  port: 22,
                  secure: true
                },
                silent:false
                //progress: true
              },
              files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './',
                src: ['./js/clubServices.js', './js/controllers.js', './css/services.css'],
                dest: '/data/media/com_memberservices/',
              }]
            }
    }
```

Initially I just received no files transferred response.  The key to getting it working was specifying the "src" files correctly in an array.  None of the information I found specifically addressed this issue.  Hope this helps someone else.  See update below

yoda57

Comment: Update on the above use of grunt-ftps-deploy.  I found that files were still not being transferred to the ftp host.  I found the ftps_deploy.js file in nod_modules/grunt-ftps-deploy/tasks has issues.  The preload function has issues.

Comment: Update on the above use of grunt-ftps-deploy.  I found that files were still not being transferred to the ftp host.  I found the ftps_deploy.js file in nod_modules/grunt-ftps-deploy/tasks has issues.  The preload function has issues.
1) near line 96,  j is incremented but there is no callback.  Should be:
j++;
 if(j === dirs.length){
     callback();
  }
Also near line 88: if (typeof list === 'undefined'){
Should be: if (typeof list.name === 'undefined'){
as list is an object or array of objects.  After fixing these directories are created if they do not exist and files are uploaded